# Why does the '=' assignment operator not work in my if statement in my didSet property observer?

Tags: swift, property-observer

```
struct Circle {
    // Properties

    var radius: Double {
        didSet {
            if oldValue < 0 {
                 radius = 0
            }
        }
    }
    var area:Double {
        get{
            return Double.pi * pow(radius, 2)
        }
    }
    var circumference: Double {
        get {
            return 2 * radius * Double.pi
        }
    }
    init() {
        radius = 0
    }
    init(radius r: Double) {
        radius = r
    }

}

// test circle

var testCircle = Circle()
print ("radius:", testCircle.radius, "area: ", testCircle.area, "circumference: ", testCircle.circumference)

var testCircle2 = Circle(radius: 2.5)
print("radius: ", testCircle2.radius, " area: ", testCircle2.area, "circumference: ", testCircle2.circumference)

var testCircle3 = Circle(radius: 20)
print("radius: ", testCircle3.radius, "area: ", testCircle3.area, "circumference: ", testCircle3.circumference)

var testCircle4 = Circle(radius: -4.5)
print("radius: ", testCircle4.radius, "area: ", testCircle4.area, "circumference: ", testCircle4.circumference)
```

Comment: The intent is to attempt to construct a circle with a radius value less than 0.  I'm new at this!

Comment: What's the purpose of this check? Is it to forbid the user from setting a negative value, and setting it to 0 if they do? Because if this is the case, you should check the current value of `radius` instead of `oldValue`. The latter will check whatever the value was *before* you made the change.

Comment: A couple administrative points: 1. Make sure your code is formatted properly. 2. You should address what your question is within the body of the question. Not in the title or the comments

Comment: A comparison is ==.

A set is =

Answer (score 2):

`didSet` property observers aren't called during `init`. You can wrap the assignment in a `defer { ... }` statement to force `didSet` to be called.

For example:

```
init(radius r: Double) {
    defer { radius = r }
}
```

If you'd like the default radius to be `0`, I'd recommend using a default parameter value for `radius` like so:

```
init(radius r: Double = 0) {
    defer { radius = r }
}
```

...that way you avoid having two init methods and still initialize a `Circle` as `Circle()` (`radius = 0`) and as `Circle(radius: 3)` (`radius = 3`).

Comment: FYI - this answer does nothing to fix the problem of code such as `someCircle.r = -4.5`

Comment: @rmaddy that wasn't the OP's question.

Comment: Sure it is. Read the title of the question. The `didSet` is written incorrectly. That fact that `didSet` wasn't being called under some circumstances is just an additional issue to be resolved.

Answer (score 1):

Remember, `didSet` is called after the property has actually been changed. `oldValue` will contain the previous value.

You want to check if the new value is negative.

Update the code to:

```
var radius: Double {
    didSet {
        if radius < 0 {
            radius = 0
        }
    }
}
```

You want to check if `radius` (the latest value) is negative.

You also need to update your `init` method:

```
init(radius r: Double) {
    radius = r >= 0 ? r : 0
}
```

This is because `didSet` and `willSet` are not called during initialization. So your `init` method needs to validate the parameter.

As a side note can further simplify your `radius` and `circumference` properties as follows:

```
var area:Double {
    return Double.pi * pow(radius, 2)
}
```

A read-only computer property doesn't need the `get { }`.